# Joins based on condition on columns

Tags: sql, impala

I have 2 tables with below columns

Table1

```
col1   col2   col3     val
 11     221     38      10
null    90      null     989
78     90       null     77
```

table2

```
col1   col2   col3  
 12     221    78
 23     null   67 
 78      90     null
```

I want output like this

```
col1   col2   col3     val     matchingcol
 11     221     38      10       col2
null    90      null     null      null
78     90       null     77       col1
```

I want to join 2 tables on first col1 if values matched then stop if not join on col2 if matches stop else join on col3 and populate val if any of column matches else null and which ever columns matching then populate that column in matchingcol column

I can achieve this by using left joins . Please let me know if there is any better approach

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: Yes I got the results I wanted using left join but I was looking if there is any better solution than left join

Comment: so post your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple joins:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t2_1.col1 is not null then 'col1'
             when t2_1.col2 is not null then 'col2'
             when t2_1.col3 is not null then 'col3'
        end) as matchingcol
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2_1
     on t2_1.col1 = t1.col1 left join
     table2 t2_2
     on t2_2.col2 = t1.col2 and t2_1.col1 is null left join
     table2 t2_3
     on t2_3.col3 = t1.col3 and t2_2.col2 is null
```

Comment: `when t2_2.col2` -- in the second case. Third case as well.

Comment: I did the same for joins part , but matchingcol sld be populated not only based on not null  but the col in both the tables sld match